# How would I make this "ascending" text in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typography

The big letters "Allison and Judah" are angled and seemingly ascending. Is this just a simple distort? Does this style have a name? I can't seem to find exactly how to replicate this myself so my google searches haven't been helpful.

Would each of "Allison", "and", and "Judah" have to be their own layers? How would I do this in photoshop?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

I left all the text in one layer, rasterized the layer, Ctrl+t to Free transform, right click -> Distort, used middle right anchor to pull text as show in gif.[image]